# Making a program that takes user input for a number 1-7 and then displays a command according to the number the user chooses. [Bash - CentOS]

Tags: linux, bash, centos

As the title says, I'm trying to make a program that has a user input a number 1-7, then displays the appropriate command for each number.

The problem I'm having is finding a good way to set each number to a command.

At first, I thought about doing something like this.

```
OSI=$(uname -a)
echo $OSI
```

But the problem with that is actually implementing it into a loop. Let's say the user is prompted like so:

```
 "Enter a number:"
```

The user enters the number 1, and number 1 is the OSI. Well if a user picks the number 2, it needs to display a different command and so forth.

This is a little bit too complicated for a beginner like myself. I've read through forums and different posts, but I cannot figure out the right commands to make this happen.

I tried doing something like this and it failed miserably:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a number:" n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 
if n1=1; then
     uname - a
else n2=2; "different command"
fi
```

I realize I'm completely garbage at bash. I'm not asking for anyone to solve this, just give me some pointers in a way that makes sense to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Look for the `case` statement in your shell's man page.

Comment: You might want to look at `select` as well (which is often used with `case` to implement this kind of menu-based interface).

Comment: The case command seems to be working well for me. It seems to be just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give this tested version a try:

```
#!/bin/bash --

printf "menu items:\n 1) uname -a\n 2) date\n q) exit\n"
read -p "Enter your choice: " response

if [ -z "$response" ] ; then
  printf "Choice invalid\n"
  exit 1
fi
if [ "$response" = q ] ; then
  exit 0
fi
if [ "$response" = 1 ] ; then
  uname -a
elif [ "$response" = 2 ] ; then
  date
else
  printf "Choice invalid\n"
fi
```

As written by @EdMorton **case** is a better option.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using the case command and it works really well!